# how to use the get as method parameter in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman, webapi

for using the query string parameters in post man to obtain single data i want to use the get method as the parameter when  i  am trying this 
 public HttpResponseMessage test(int id) it is showing error that

**No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:53720/api/test/1'.**

**No type was found that matches the controller named 'test'.**

the code is:

```
   public class DefaultController: ApiController {
    public object Conn { get; private set;}

    [Route("api/test/id")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage test(int id) {
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     string conname = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conname);
     conn.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select *from Employees", conn);
     SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     sda.Fill(ds);
     return new HttpResponseMessage {
      Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
     };
    }
   }
```

Comment: please mark it as answer if that solves your problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stack-overflow   https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Your `id` is a variable parameter in your route and your route does not look correct. Try with {} around id. Like below.

```
[Route("api/test/{id}")] // <===== notice that id is in {}
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage test(int id)
```

You can also use Route Constraints if you want to restrict how the parameters in the route template are matched. General syntax is `{parameter:constraint}`

So in your case, it would be something like:

```
[Route("api/test/{id:int}")]
```

Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) for more details